# Which one is correct I want to hear he/him singing?

Tags: pronouns

Which one is correct?

> 1 I want to hear he singing?

> 2 I want to hear him singing?

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff. _He_ - subject. _Him_ - object.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:
I want to hear him sing.
Here's why:
He is a subjective pronoun.
Example:
He is driving in a truck.
Him is an objective pronoun.
Example:
I want to travel with him to the circus.